# UPDATE table using IN and COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

I am updating my table setting a field named "status" based on the condition that the total number of distinct rows should be more than 10 and less than 13. The query is as follows:

```
update myTable set status='Established'
where id IN(select id, count(*) as c 
            from myTable 
            where year>=1996 and year<=2008 
    group by id
    having count(distinct year)>=10 and count(distinct year)<=13)
```

The problem is, I'm getting error1241 that is "operand should contain 1 column"! Could you please advise how can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to express with such a weird query: `id IN(select id, count(*) as c ...)` ? You're comparing a single value of `id` column with a tuple returned from a nested query

Comment: I omitted the WHERE part from the inner query. Basically, I want to find all the book authors who have published a book at least in 10 years out of a 13 year time interval.\

Comment: `count(distinct year)>=10 and count(distinct year)>=13` --- ??? If a number is more or equal than 13, it's definitely more than 10

Answer (score 1):

The result of the sub query must return only 1 column :

```
update myTable set status='Established'
where id IN(select id 
            from myTable 
    group by id
    having count(distinct year)>=10 and count(distinct year)>=13)
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, an `update` with a `join` often performs better than an `update` with a subquery in the `where` clause.

This version might have better performance:

```
update myTable join
       (select id, count(*) as c 
        from myTable 
        where year >= 1996 and year <= 2008 
        group by id
        having count(distinct year) >= 10 and count(distinct year) <= 13
       ) filter
       on myTable.id = filter.id
    set status = 'Established';
```

I will also note that you have a table where a column called `id` is not unique among the rows.  Typically, such a column would be a primary key, so the `having` clause would always fail (there would only be one row).

Comment: Many thanks for the informative comment. Actually, the performance of my previous query was quite an issue! Regarding the id, I tried to simplify the query and put it here but id is not the primary key. The only problem with the new query is I'm getting sql error 1205! I changed InnoDB lock wait time-out to 400 but still it's not working!

Comment: @Ashkan . . . Does the subquery (`filter`) run in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: Add an index on `mytable(id)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
update myTable 
 set status='Established'
where id IN(select id from myTable
            group by id
            having count(distinct year)>=10 
            and count(distinct year)>=13)
```

You are using IN operator and then you inner query returns two columns id and count(*) it should return only one column back.